# xslt select all the <tag> elements that follow a particular <parenttag> element

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider I have this XML file:

```
<p>my name is :
  <bold>reza</bold>
  <bold>saket</bold>
  <bold>ali</bold>
  <bold>abadi</bold>
</p>
<p>my name is :
  <bold>
    <italic>mehran</italic>
  </bold>
  <bold>
    <italic>bazargan</italic>
  </bold>
  <bold>
    <italic>dashtestani</italic>
  </bold>
</p>
```

Now I wish that the output will be :

```
<p> my name is :
  <bold>reza saket ali abadi</bold>
</p>
<p>
  <bold>
    <italic>mehran bazargan dashtestani</italic>
  </bold>
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will usually get better results if you show what you have tried, so people can help you figure out what is wrong.  If you don't show what you have tried, some readers may think that you are just trying to get other people to do your work for you.  So:  what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'd write an identity transform and then modify it by adding templates like this (not tested).  First, special handling for bold and italic elements:

```
<xsl:template match='bold | italic'>
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <!--* if our preceding sibling has the same element
        * type, then we have already been processed; 
        * do nothing. *-->
    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = $name]"/>

    <!--* if our next following sibling has the same element
        * type, then incorporate it. *-->
    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = $name]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" 
                             mode="incorporation"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>

    <!--* otherwise, proceed normally *-->
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, templates to handle all the node types we may encounter in incorporation mode:

```
<xsl:template match='bold | italic' mode="incorporation">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  <!--* if our next following sibling has the same element
      * type, then incorporate it. *-->
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = $name]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" 
                         mode="incorporation"/>
  </xsl:if>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='comment()' 
              mode='incorporation'>
 <xsl:comment>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:comment>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" 
                      mode="incorporation"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='processing-instruction()' 
              mode='incorporation'>
 <xsl:variable name="pitarget" select="name()"/>
 <xsl:processing-instruction name="{$pitarget}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:processing-instruction>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" 
                      mode="incorporation"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--* this one accidentally omitted in first version *-->
<xsl:template match='text()' mode='incorporation'>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" 
                       mode="incorporation"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, a template to suppress nodes we have already encountered in incorporation mode, to prevent duplication:

```
<xsl:template match='node()[not(self::*) 
                     and preceding-sibling::*[1]
                     [self::bold or self::italic]]'/>
```

This handles just one level of bold or italic; since you want to handle them nested, as in your second example, you will need to run it twice -- or repeatedly, until its output is identical to its input, if you may have bold and italic elements nested more than two deep.

Comment: Perhaps you *should* test it before springing it on the unsuspecting world. I did, and it returns `<p> my name is : <bold>reza </bold></p>` for the first paragraph. I don't know if you noticed, but in the source document there is a plain-text space separating the stylized nodes.

Comment: I don't think that the spaces in between the `bold` tags are intentional, rather the OP did not know how to format code correctly on SO. In the expected output XML, there are spaces enclosed in the `bold`elements that were outside `bold` in the input XML.

Comment: @ Mathias Müller "I don't think that the spaces in between the bold tags are intentional" Well, I do. The input is obviously HTML and without the spaces the names would be rendered incorrectly, e.g. "**MathiasMüller**" instead of "**Mathias Müller**". Your modifications to the original question created a new question rather than *editing* the existing one.

Comment: Thank you (@user3016153) for pointing out the problem; I seem to have broken the 'incorporation' mode while cleaning up the design.  I've added a new template for text() in that mode which seems to fix the problem you identified.